# Can you make your own rendering pipeline?

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, pipeline

I want to write a renderer, but do i really have to use the OpenGL pipeline, cant i make my own? Is there a way i can write all the code for the GPU and CPU, from memory management to rasterization, or do i have to use the already provided pipeline? If i cant do it in OpenGL where can i? Can i get some directions?
In what language do i write the GPU code and how do i use it on the GPU?

Comment: Vulcan gets you closer to the GPU, if you want to get any closer you'd have to speak to each individual GPU vendor to get their low level interface the drivers use (I doubt you'd have much success with this)

Comment: If you really wanted to avoid any "graphics API" you could go implement the computations in CUDA or OpenCL but (1) performance would probably suffer a lot and (2) you'd still have to use some sort of graphics API to get the image to the screen. Vulkan gives you much lower level control over the hardware than OpenGL does, but if you haven't used *either* I suggest you start with OpenGL and only transition to Vulkan later if you find that the latest OpenGL is genuinely insufficient for your needs.

Comment: On the other hand, you could take the long road and write your own driver, own graphics card interface and so and on - or something... I'm sure it's possible, but I'm also sure it's not worth trying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consumer-grade GPUs as they currently standard are not CPUs. You don't "program" a graphics pipeline. The graphics pipeline is what it is because that's how GPUs are designed to work. Obviously, different specific GPUs will have different implementations, but basic elements of the rendering pipeline are all fundamental parts of the hardware. The parts of the pipeline which are programmable are only programmable to the extent the GPU allows it and for the purpose for which that stage is intended (with some flexibility).

Future GPUs may be more flexible, and there are even some [alternative pipelines for vertex processing](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/NV/NV_mesh_shader.txt) in certain modern GPUs. But we're not at the point yet where you can just make things up as you like. GPUs are designed for efficiency; their limitations are there to help things stay on an efficient path.

Memory management is an entirely separate issue. Vulkan and similar command-buffer APIs allow much more low-level memory management functionality compared to immediate APIs like OpenGL. However, it should be well understood that command buffer APIs are *not* for hobby programmers. These APIs are not friendly in the slightest; they require you to be keenly aware of many details that immediate APIs hide from you, and they will not tell you when you break their rules.

Comment: My goal isn't to make an application that can render stuff, but to know how it does it. I want to do ALL the math for the rendering. I made a renderer on the CPU with WinAPI, all the way to drawing textures on the triangles, but it got slow very fast, i got to rendering 10 000 textured triangles with 20 fps, so there wasnt room to add shadows, and all more advanced stuff, i wrote algorithms for drawing triangles and texture mapping and all that stuff.

Comment: @Mark: But you *already know* how it does it; you proved that when you wrote your software renderer. You know how graphics works. GPUs are for when you want graphics to work *fast*. And that means living within their limitations. Once you've written the code for a triangle rasterizer, you have learned everything there is to know about a triangle rasterizer. Once you've written code for interpolating parameters across a triangle, there's nothing more to learn there. Let the hardware do its job so that you can go do yours.

Comment: But i cant add shadows, and normal maps, etc. because it got slow. And i would like it to be fast, usable. And i would also like to know GPU programming more. I also tried Windows AMP and OpenCL but it is slow.

Comment: @Mark: If you're one of the people who believes that they're not really doing/learning a thing unless they implement it completely from the ground up, there's no real help for you. There's no middle ground; if you want "fast, usable", then you cannot write it all yourself. You have to use the hardware. And since you've already learned how a rasterizer works, I don't see what the problem is in ditching your software rasterizer in favor of the hardware one. You learned what their is to learn; what more can you gain?

Comment: I was always wondering how Blender renders stuff and was always interested into doing it myself. And i know that it took a lot of people and a lot of time to make Blender (and that it used OpenGL once) but i want to see how much i can go, maybe your right, maybe there no help for me.

Comment: @Mark: My point is that *you know how it works now*. You have the answers you were looking for. You've learned all you can from this method. Move on to learning how to work with GPUs, not how to make them do things your way.

Comment: *Blender (and that it used OpenGL once)* As far as I can tell, Blender still uses OpenGL. That is, at least for rendering the ui/editor/preview. The renderer itself is not a rasterizer but a raytracer, but that is a completely different story.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/zauonlok/renderer. Should be easy enough to get a demo working on your machine. It does struggle with performance compared to a hardware renderer with the same feature set, but is still a very impressive demonstration of what can be achieved in a software-only pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a library that makes calls directly to the graphics drivers, or you could write a custom pipeline that runs on the cpu, which would functionally be an emulator for dedicated graphics hardware, but it would be complex, unreliable, slow, and would likely cost you a lot of time to implement, with very little return on investment.

As has been mentioned in comments, GPU's work the way they do, because they were designed on a hardware level to do it that way. The OpenGL/DirectX/Vulkan api's just allow you to have more, or less control over that pipeline, and to plug custom shader stages in.

The reason you cannot write your own rasterizer, is because it is a stage in the pipeline, in which is is pretty much as efficient as it can be. Your version is unlikely to be better.

Don't concern yourself too much with the non-programmable parts of the pipeline. That is the purview of hardware engineers and driver programmers.

If you want lots of control over the existing hardware, try DX12 or Vulkan/Metal. They're about as close as you can get to the hardware as a programmer, without writing custom drivers.